# How to stop OS X from switching input method (keyboard layout) automatically?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

After using the wireless keyboard that comes with the iMac, I have switched to a MS Ergo Natural 4000 one. Surprisingly I had to install extra software as OS X could not work out which keyboard I had.

After which I went into sys prefs and set the main input method to be "British - Microsoft" first and "Swiss German" second (what the wireless keyboard is), on the "input sources" tab:

[image]

However... OS X keeps resetting my input method back to Swiss German which is driving me bananas.

I have the flag thingy top right so I can see when this changes.

N.B. I have "input source options" set to "use the same one in all documents" which I am assuming means keep the language the same for anything running.

It also flips back on the login page.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have also just noticed that for some applications, it is not even possible to select "British - Microsoft" e.g. Preview, QuickTimeplayer. Other applications like firefox and itunes work fine (although they do still keep switching back to swiss german)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The MS layout for the keyboard on OSX sucks

Use this layout instead
http://liyang.hu/osx-british.xhtml

Seems to work

Comment: This does not actually answer your own question!

Answer (score 27):

If the system is switching language without you asking to do so, it means that the current input source somehow becomes unavailable. This can happen if you are using a custom input source (put under ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts) and then lock your screen. The lock screen is owned by the system and thus does not have access to your custom layouts, only the system-wide ones. The current source being unavailable, it will automatically revert to another one.

To resolve this issue, ensure that your custom keyboard layout is put under /Library and not /Users/You/Libary. After moving the file, remove the input source from the list, reboot and then put it back again.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had my layouts in ~/Library and my app-store-installed apps couldn't see them and I had no idea why.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. This has been such a huge annoyance! It always happened when a Authorize prompt opened up and after log out.

Comment: This works, thank you very much for this! Put the .layout file to "/Library/Keyboard Layouts" and then do a full OS reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much! This should be the accepted answer for sure.

Comment: This doesn’t work as of 10.15, as soon as I open the AppStore, it switches back to default.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either.  My custom keyboard layout is in /Library, but the OS switches away from it whenever I lock the screen.

Answer (score 13):

One possibility that I had in a similar case is that you are hitting the keyboard shortcut to switch input sources.

In Snow Leopard preferences, the default to select the previous input source is Command-Space. In your screen capture of the Language & Text preferences you can see that this shortcut is active (the other shortcut, to select the next input source, is inactive in that screen capture):

[image: Input source shortcut]

It's a bit odd<sup>†</sup> that Command-Space is used, as that is also used for Spotlight. But if a shortcut is assigned multiple times, then Snow Leopard would show a warning, which *your* screen capture does *not* show. So, Command-Space won't activate Spotlight on your Mac:

[image: Input source shortcut with warning]

<sup><sup>†</sup> From [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343): *Command-Space: Show or hide the Spotlight search field (if multiple languages are installed, may rotate through enabled script systems)*</sup>

Comment: My 10.6 has a disabled (default) of Command-Space (rather than Option-Space) for "Select the previous input source". I don't know why it's that, because Command-Space has been Spotlight for ages. I also don't know what disabled it. But: maybe *some* installations still have that Command-Space shortcut assigned twice? That would show a warning in the keyboard preferences though.

Comment: When I switch to an app that does *not* support the "British - Microsoft" setting i.e. automatically assumes "Swiss German", it appears to switch it for ALL applications. I don't understand why not all applications support 'another' language and I also don't understand why this forces the other applications to pick up the change.

Comment: It is a global setting for the keyboard and thus for all apps.

Comment: Sorry it is not - each app remembers what was used last - see http://mac.finerthingsin.com/2010/01/18/keyboard-layouts-tied-to-applications/

Comment: Actually it appears to have both. Single global setting and setting per app. The problem lies in the fact that once you set it to a language which is not supported by all apps, then it will switch to the other one. It sucks, seriously.

Comment: For Catalina, find this at Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a custom `.keylayout` created with Ukelele, manually copied over to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`.

I had two input sources configured under Keyboard Settings. A built-in one (British) and my custom keyboard layout.

In some applications, I could switch between the two keyboard layouts freely. However, there were applications (Calendar, Safari) where the OS refused to switch to my custom layout. If I had the custom layout active, the layout would automatically change back to the British one as soon as I switched over to Calendar.

After a lot of head scratching, I downloaded a known good custom `.keylayout` from the internet. I compared this layout to mine and noticed a few differences.

This is what I had in my custom layout:

```
<keyboard group="126" id="-2" name="Custom Layout" maxout="3">
```

And this is what I changed it to (using the downloaded one as a reference):

```
<keyboard group="0" id="16003" name="Custom Layout" maxout="1">
```

I removed my custom layout under Keyboard Settings, logged out, logged back in, and added the custom layout back again.

Unsure if it was the `group`, the `id`, or the `maxout` value causing the problem, but I am glad to say the issue is gone now.

As a side note, what is interesting, is that I have been using this custom layout for a decade, and never experienced this issue. Now that I am using a new Mac (with macOS Monterey 12.4) is when I first come across this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been struggling with my `BÉPO` keyboard layout for months, and your change seems to have solved it. Hurray!
(As a side note, I confirm this issue appeared with the switch to Monterey)

Answer (score 0):

*@Brunni*'s answer from 2013 helped me a lot with this, but it doesn't solve the problem completely in 2022 (see comments below that answer).

I had the same problem as *@CharlesRezk* and *@a.s.t.r.o* on MacOS 12.1 when I tried to install/copy a keyboard layout bundle created with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) by doing Copy & Paste in the Finder. MacOS asks for my PW, and after providing it, it copies the files to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`, but they maintain my user as owner rather then setting it to `root`. If the owner is not `root`, you get exactly the behaviour reported in the original question.

The solution is to use the Terminal and either copy the files as `root` or do `sudo cp ...`, which sets the permissions right. Specifically you can do:

```
$ sudo su -
$ cd /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts
$ cp -r /path/to/ukelele.bundle ./
```

Works like charm now... ;)

BTW, the "Install" feature in the [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/)-UI (v3.5.4) does not work properly. So after creating your keyboard layout, copy the bundle manually to `/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts`.

Other than this, [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) was really useful to create the new layout bundle.